# Relationships in has many laravel

Tags: join, laravel-5, relationship, has-many

I have three tables `units`, `renters`, `renter_units`. Fields of `render_units` table is `id` , `unit_id`, `renter_id`.

My `Render` model is

```
public function renter_unit() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\RenterUnit');
    }
```

And in my `RentersController`

```
$renters = Renter::with('renter_unit')->get();
```

So the `$renders` array shows

```
Collection {#212 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Renter {#206 ▼
      #fillable: array:3 [▶]
      #table: "renters"
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:7 [▶]
      #original: array:7 [▶]
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "renter_unit" => Collection {#210 ▼
          #items: array:2 [▼
            0 => RenterUnit {#213 ▼
              #fillable: array:2 [▶]
              #table: "renter_units"
              #guarded: array:1 [▶]
              #connection: null
              #primaryKey: "id"
              #perPage: 15
              +incrementing: true
              +timestamps: true
              #attributes: array:5 [▼
                "id" => 1
                "unit_id" => 1
                "renter_id" => 1
                "created_at" => "2016-06-11 02:40:44"
                "updated_at" => "2016-06-11 02:40:44"
              ]
              #original: array:5 [▶]
              #relations: []
              #hidden: []
              #visible: []
              #appends: []
              #dates: []
              #dateFormat: null
              #casts: []
              #touches: []
              #observables: []
              #with: []
              #morphClass: null
              +exists: true
              +wasRecentlyCreated: false
            }
            1 => RenterUnit {#214 ▶}
          ]
        }
      ]
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want the `relationship` array for `renter_unit` field too. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use [Many-To-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship. If so, then you don't  need any pivot class like `RenterUnit`, only `renter_unit` table
Then your code will be like below

Renter.php

```
public function units() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Unit');
}
```

Unit.php

```
public function renters() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Renter');
}
```

In your RentersController you can access to units related with each renter instance

```
$renters = Renter::with('units')->get();
foreach($renters as $renter) {
     $units = $renter->units; //here they are, it's a collection
}
```